# how to create two thumbnails for image virtuemart

Tags: joomla, thumbnails, joomla3.0, virtuemart

i want create two thumbnails for each product images,but Virtuemart only get one option to this. i used:

```
echo $product->images[0]->displayMediaThumb('class="browseProductImage"', false,'',true,false,false,540,200);
```

but this line not create thumbnails.and return older thumbnail